# using YCSB Benchmark with only a single node

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, ycsb

I want to use YCSB Benchmark for a single node with MongoDB and another single node with Couchbase, with a computer  with only 512MB of RAM and one core each.
Is it doable? will I be able to see how the workloads are performing, the throughput? 
Will I be able to compare both databases performance correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: No

**Long answer**: There are several weak points in your experimental setup:

1. MongoDB and Couchbase are designed to be distributed. A single node deployment is only made on testing purposes. Therefore, if you benchmark only 1 node, you won't get a valid performance result.
2. Your amount of RAM seems to be very insufficient for:

   1. YCSB: expect YSCB to take at least 2 GB RAM while running.
   2. Your databases: Couchbase is (I think) a in-memory database. Its advantage is then to use RAM to speed up operations. If your starve it, the performances will be catastrophic. Generally, you should give databases several GB to make them work properly.
3. If you want to have an idea of how YCSB works, please use the `basic` switch as written in the [documentation](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload#step-5-load-the-data).